# VBA for formatting stops in specific range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Well I guess it might be a silly question but i could not figure ir out by myself.

I have a WB that has various macros  within it. One for copy a template(creating a new WS every time it is necessary) that the user fills ups. After, one macro for coping the results to a 'Summary' WS, then another that applies a formula, after that, one that applies a score (good, bad, ok) and the last one that copies the format of scpecifics cells to give a proper formating to print it.

This last one is acting wierd. I created more than 40 WS (copping the template) but the formatting one stops on the 25th line. I don't know why.

I have used the formula to copy till last row, but nothing can make this thing work.

Bellow follows the result and the code. I thought that the problem could be that I compressed all the command in one sub, so I break it in variuos ones and created a 'trigger' button to activate all of this commands.

If my explaniation is not enought, just ask for more info.

In advance, thanks for all the help!

[Erro on the formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgGBo.png)

---

The code I used.

==============

```
Sub FormatarCab()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Using Find Function (Provided by Bob Ulmas)
LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Para o cabeçalho
Worksheets("Descritivo").Range("B50").Copy
Worksheets("Avaliação Todos").Range("A1:E1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

'-------------------------------------

```
Sub FormatarNome()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Using Find Function (Provided by Bob Ulmas)
LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Para os Nomes das Abas
Worksheets("Descritivo").Range("B52").Copy
Worksheets("Avaliação Todos").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats


Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

'-------------------------------------

```
Sub FormatarConceito()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Using Find Function (Provided by Bob Ulmas)
LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Para o Conceito
Worksheets("Descritivo").Range("B54").Copy
Worksheets("Avaliação Todos").Range("E2:E" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats


Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

'-------------------------------------

```
Sub FormatarValores()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Using Find Function (Provided by Bob Ulmas)
LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Para os valoreso
Worksheets("Descritivo").Range("B56").Copy
Worksheets("Avaliação Todos").Range("B2:D" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats


Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

==============

The sctructure for the function LastRow

==============

```
Option Explicit

'Common Functions required for all routines:

Function LastRow(Sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = Sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=Sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            searchdirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function LastCol(Sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = Sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=Sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            searchdirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

==============

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but you don't appear to be using the functions, you are using a variable called LastRow.

Comment: Also you don't need a separate procedure for each sheet.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (I'm learning VBA by myself, so I copy a lot of codes and reuse the ones that worked before), when I declared LastRow as Long, it is now being actually used on the formula?

Comment: You are assigning a value to the variable in this line `LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row` but this has nothing to do with your function called LastRow which I cannot see you calling anywhere. As I say it may not be the cause of your problem but you should be clear about what you are doing.

Comment: Resuming, I'm trying to copy a style from a cell and apply it till last row on the ranges as shown. 1 - Can i substitute the LastRow one the VBA for other thing? 2 - How can I substitute it? 3 - As you say, I'm now understanding that I don't 'need' the Structure for the fuction, so, can I delete it?

Comment: 1) I don't understand why you have four bits of code? 2) In your LastRow line you should specify a sheet name rather than active sheet. 3) I think in that case you can dispense with the functions. Edit 4) See CLR's answer!

Comment: @SJR Thanks! Visualizing the answer of CLR I could see what you were talking, thanks for explaining it too for me!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Correct me if it is a 'unsecured' solution. The users of the WB have none VBA knowledge. Just hiding the references for the case could secure that the error you mentioned would not happen, right? or not? Sincerely, I cannot understand fully your comment, I'm not a full coder or developer, sorry.

Comment: If `Find` doesn't find anything, it returns `Nothing`, which is an invalid object reference - invoking `.Row` on that invalid reference will always throw an error. The solution is to `Set result = sht.Cells.Find(...)` and then `If Not result Is Nothing Then LastRow = result.Row Else LastRow = 1`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I can imagine how this erro can happen, if my reference for the for the `find` command get deleted or disapear this would happen. Again, thank you for the knowledge and you time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the LastRow function that you've added to the bottom of the code but don't actually use, you're setting a variable called `LastRow` with the value of the lowest cell found in `sht` - which is `Set` to `ActiveSheet`.

You then paste down from `E2` to `E` & LastRow - but not necessarily of `ActiveSheet` - in fact you do this on `Worksheets("Avaliação Todos")`

You want `LastRow` to be based on the bottom row of the sheet you're going to paste upon so - it should look like this:

```
Sub FormatarCab()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Avaliação Todos")

        'Using Find Function (Provided by Bob Ulmas)
        LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        'Para o cabeçalho
        Worksheets("Descritivo").Range("B50").Copy
        .Range("A1:E1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

'-------------------------------------

Sub FormatarNome()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Avaliação Todos")

        'Using Find Function (Provided by Bob Ulmas)
        LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        'Para os Nomes das Abas
        Worksheets("Descritivo").Range("B52").Copy
        .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

'-------------------------------------

Sub FormatarConceito()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Avaliação Todos")

        'Using Find Function (Provided by Bob Ulmas)
        LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        'Para o Conceito
        Worksheets("Descritivo").Range("B54").Copy
        .Range("E2:E" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

'-------------------------------------

Sub FormatarValores()


    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Avaliação Todos")

        'Using Find Function (Provided by Bob Ulmas)
        LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        'Para os valoreso
        Worksheets("Descritivo").Range("B56").Copy
        .Range("B2:D" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer and the explanation. I'm newbie to VBA/Macro, I can copy fairly good, but there are a lot of nuances in it I can't perceive. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to find the last row or column you can use the below:

```
Dim lc As Long
Dim lr As Long

'Change the 1 to whatever row you would want to be able to check for the last true column.
lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'determines total number of columns

'Change the "A" to whatever row would show the last row and be consistent for all your worksheets
lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'determines total number of rows including header
```

The above assumes that you have consistent data

Comment: Thank you for the option @John ! I'll try it too =)